# Change the time based on the gmt area on Android

Tags: java, android

I'm a beginner in android development and I've been searching for hours to find an answer for my question but I didn't really understand anything I found.

The match between 2 teams is starting at 20:00 gmt and I want to make it + - based on the area. For example in germany +1 gmt the time should be 21:00. I only want the hours and minutes format like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## tl;dr

```java
OffsetDateTime
.of(
    LocalDate.of( 2021 , Month.MARCH , 23 ) ,
    LocalTime.of( 20 , 0 ) ,
    ZoneOffset.UTC
)                                                 // Returns a `OffsetDateTime` object.
.atZoneSameInstant(
    ZoneId.of( "Europe/Berlin" )
)                                                 // Returns a `ZonedDateTime` object.
.toLocalTime()                                    // Returns a `LocalTime` object.
.toString()                                       // Returns a `String` object, with text in standard ISO 8601 format.
```

> 21:00

## Details

Location does not necessarily correlate to time zone. Users choose their time zone as a preference. Servers should generally be set to UTC (an offset of zero). You can get the JVM’s current default time zone by calling [`ZoneId.systemDefault`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/ZoneId.html#systemDefault()). If crucial, you should explicitly ask the user to confirm their desired zone.

> I only want the hours and minutes format like that.

Date-time objects are not text, and do not have a "format". Think in terms of the logic needed for handling date-time values rather than in terms of manipulating strings.

> starting at 20:00 gmt and I want to make it + - based on the area

Representing that 8 PM in UTC (the new GMT):

```
LocalDate tomorrow = LocalDate.now( ZoneOffset.UTC ).plusDays( 1 ) ;
LocalTime eightPM = LocalTime.of( 20 , 0 ) ;
OffsetDateTime odt = OffsetDateTime.of( tomorrow , eightPM , ZoneOffset.UTC ) ;
```

> For example in germany +1 gmt the time should be 21:00

Define your desired time zone.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "Europe/Berlin" ) ;
```

Adjust from the `OffsetDateTime` to a `ZonedDateTime`.

```
ZonedDateTime zdt = odt.atZoneSameInstant( z ) ;
```

See that [code run live at IdeOne.com](https://ideone.com/wKMmbu).

```
odt.toString(): 2021-02-17T20:00Z
zdt.toString(): 2021-02-17T21:00+01:00[Europe/Berlin]
```

The `odt` & `zdt` objects seen here both refer to the very same simultaneous moment, the same point on the timeline.

This has all been covered many times before on Stack Overflow. Search to learn more.

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes. Hibernate 5 & JPA 2.2 support *java.time*.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), [**Java SE 11**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_11), and later  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.

  - [**Java 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9) brought some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Most of the *java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android (26+) bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), a process known as [*API desugaring*](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support#library-desugaring) brings a [subset of the *java.time*](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) functionality not originally built into Android.

    - If the desugaring does not offer what you need, the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above) to Android. See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

[image: Table of which java.time library to use with which version of Java or Android]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Is there anyway to get the zone ID? I mean I don't want already to write the zone ID inside the brackets like this ZoneId.of( "Europe/Berlin" ) can I make it automatically based on the location? Anyway thanks for your help.

Comment: @Amed Location does not necessarily correlate to time zone. Users choose their time zone as a preference. Servers should generally be set to UTC (an offset of zero). You can get the JVM’s current default time zone by calling `ZoneId.systemDefault`. If crucial, you should explicitly ask the user to confirm their desired zone.

Answer (score 0):

It's not Android specific but just a general question about Java.

Use `Calendar` and `SimpleDateFormat` like this:

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
calendar.set(2021, 1, 16, 20, 00, 00); // 2021-02-16T20:00:00 GMT

SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");
simpleDateFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT+01:00"));

System.out.println(simpleDateFormat.format(calendar.getTime()));
```

Set (input) your date as `GMT`. Then format it `GMT+01:00` with `SimpleDateFormat` and print (output) it.

Comment: These terrible date-time classes were supplanted years ago by the modern *java.time* classes defined in JSR 310. Suggesting these legacy classes in 2021 is poor advice.

Comment: @BasilBourque You're right. As you posted in your answer, introducing those new features to Android was delayed. For I didn't know his target API level, I chose conventional but may be *safer* way. However, your answer is excellent.

Comment: The latest Android tooling brings most of the *java.time* functionality to older Android runtimes via *API desugaring*. So really no reason to use `Calendar`, `Date`, or `SimpleDateFormat` ever again.

Comment: @BasilBourque Thank you for your detailed info. Honestly, it was rather me than Amed who learned a lot :)